# How to redirect to a new page in react and typescript after an animation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, redirect

I am trying to send the user to the login page after an initial animation has finished. It takes two seconds for the animation to execute so I set a settimeout that takes 3 seconds to execute but then it says that it is not possible to load the web page in http://localhost/pages/Login.tsx
and it gives me a net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE error.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { IonApp } from '@ionic/react';
import "./css/main.css";

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("set timeout")
      var goToLogin: HTMLElement = document.querySelector("#goToLogin") as HTMLElement;
      goToLogin?.click();
      // window.location = "/pages/Login.tsx";
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  return(
    <IonApp class="app">
      
      <a id="goToLogin" href="./pages/Login.tsx"></a>
      
      <div>
        <svg id="core-logo" width="117" height="60" viewBox="0 0 307 157" fill="#fff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M67.824 78.088H88.56C88.56 83.08 87.744 87.544 86.112 91.48C84.48 95.416 82.224 98.776 79.344 101.56C76.464 104.344 73.056 106.456 69.12 107.896C65.184 109.638 153.848 212.094 153.932 212.742 154.004C213.414 154.1 214.074 154.148 214.722 1288.974 133.336 289.998 132.248C291.054 131.16 291.582 129.48 291.582 127.208ZM283.758 128.744V132.008H281.694V122.312H285.15C286.654 122.312 287.694 122.584 288.27 123.128C288.878 123.64 289.182 124.44 289.182 125.528C289.182 126.328 289.006 126.984 288.654 127.496C288.302 127.976 287.774 128.312 287.07 128.504L289.422 132.008H286.83L284.862 128.744H283.758ZM287.07 125.528C287.07 125.08 286.926 124.744 286.638 124.52C286.35 124.296 285.854 124.184 285.15 124.184H283.758V127.016H285.15C285.854 127.016 286.35 126.904 286.638 126.68C286.926 126.424 287.07 126.04 287.07 125.528Z" fill="white"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
          
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I redirect to the login page?
Here is my file structure:
[image: File structure]

**UPDATED**

Now my app looks like this:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.push("/login");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  return(
    <IonApp class="app">
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
      
      <div>
        <svg id="core-logo" width="117" height="60" viewBox="0 0 307 157" fill="#fff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M67.824 78.088H88.56C88.56 83.08 87.744 87.544 86.112 91.48C84.48 95.416 82.224 98.776 12 287.07 128.504L289.422 132.008H286.83L284.862 128.744H283.758ZM287.07 125.528C287.07 125.08 286.926 124.744 286.638 124.52C286.35 124.296 285.854 124.184 285.15 124.184H283.758V127.016H285.15C285.854 127.016 286.35 126.904 286.638 126.68C286.926 126.424 287.07 126.04 287.07 125.528Z" fill="white"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
          
    </IonApp>
  );
};
```

I also encapsulated the app component in BrowserRouter in `index.tsx`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

UPDATE 2
Removed the router in index.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {/* <Router> */}
      <App />
    {/* </Router> */}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And used:

```
useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.push("/login");
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Instead of useEffect.

Now I can navigate through the url bar in chrome inspect but every time I render a new page the App page renders again.
And I get the following error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) library to create such behavior for you app.

Here is an example of what you need to do to create a simple app with such routings.

First you need to create three files:

- App.tsx
- LoginPage.tsx
- AnimationPage.tsx

**App.tsx** - is you router file where we will specify all routes and link them with components. Here we need [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter), [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) and [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) components from `react-router-dom`.

```
// App.tsx
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AnimationPage from "./AnimationPage.tsx";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage.tsx";

let App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`/animation`} component={AnimationPage} />
        <Route exact path={`/login`} component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**LoginPage.tsx** - simple page with one button that redirects us to the page with animation.

```
// LoginPage.tsx
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

let LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/animation`} >
      <button>Go to animation page</button>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

**AnimationPage** - page with the same behavior as the page from your example. Here we need `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom` to be able to redirect our app to particular page right from the function body.

```
// AnimationPage.tsx
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let AnimationPage = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.push(`/login`);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  return <SomeAnomationComponent />;
};
```

All the docs for all hooks and components you can hind [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

Have fun!

Comment: But history is `undefined`. It says on the chrome dev tools cannot read property push of undefined.

Comment: Please be careful and repeat everything as in the example.

`history` is defined in AnimationPage.tsx file before `useEffect`.

Comment: But for the animation I used css. I didn't create an animation with React. And I am using Ionic too. I just wanted when the app page is loaded after 3 seconds it redirects to the login page.

Comment: I got this error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. What is this?

Comment: Now I get this error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: It's possible to figure the reason of infinite loop by the code in your post. But I it's bad idea to place svg and router in one file.

Comment: If you want fast result - just copy my example. If you want to figure out, what's going on - you need to take a closer look at `react-router-dom`. You made a mistake when you placed something outside of the router. Router must wrap everything that should be connected with particular path.

Comment: Also useIonViewWillEnter is superfluous here

Comment: Here I recreated your idea in CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-mccarthy-psu2z

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thank you. I moved the svg to a different page and put only the router in App page